# number animator - wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am working on a wordpress site and would like to add a label that shows an animating number to the target number.

Here is an example (top right of this page) https://servicestack.net/

I have found a few jQuery based animators. If you can point out some more such animators, it will be helpful to pick the best one. For my animation, the target number is static (it is not coming from any database or data source). I should be able to say target of 100 and start from 94 so the number can animate from 94 to 100.

Here is one that I found
http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/counter

Comment: so where is the code of what you have tried so far, and what exact issue are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

I made an element with two extra attributes which looks like this:

```
<div class="number" target="100" start="94"></div>
```

It should contain the number you want to display.

Also Ive added this jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var element = $(".number").first();
    element.text(element.attr("start"));
    setTimeout(function(){
        step(element);
    }, randTime());
});

function step(element) {
    element.text(+element.text() + 1);
    if (element.text() != element.attr("target")) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            step(element);
        }, randTime());
    }
};

function randTime() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 400);
};
```

Which should be pretty much selfexplaining.

See also [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4AGk/).